# The usage of ～ば

Tags: translation, conditionals

I know that ば is to indicate that "if A happens, B will happen too".

So, today, I've listened a song and it says:

> I gotta believe
>   I don't wanna know 下手な真実なら
>   I don't wanna know　知らないくらいがいいのに
>   Why? Why? Why? Why?
>   気づけば　I came too far.

(The mixture of Japanese and English is in the original.) I can't translate the last verse. I don't think that it means "If I realize". So I would like to know what is the meaning of this "気づけば".

Comment: Is the part in inverted commas, over two lines and in two languages the sentence you are trying to understand?

Comment: Sorry. Now I've edited. The sentence I want to know is "気づけば　I came too far"

Comment: It would be clearer to provide the original first (with perhaps a bit of context), then your attempt at a translation.

Comment: Sorry again. Here it is  " I don't wanna know heta na shinjitsu nara
I don't wanna know shiranai kurai ga ii noni
Why? Why? Why? Why? Kizukeba I came too far"                                                            From this website https://kamenrider.fandom.com/wiki/EXCITE

Answer (score 4):

It is a relatively minor, rhetorical usage of [**ば**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172830/meaning/m0u/):

> **２**
>   ㋑ある事態・結果に気づくきっかけとなった動作・作用を表す。…したところが。「ふと見れば西空は夕焼けだった」「思えば悲しい出来事だった」

It has little conditional sense here, just takes sensory verbs before and some fact after, describing that the speaker just have recognized the fact (often belatedly).

> 気づけば　I came too far.
>   = *When I realized it, I had (already) come too far.*
>   = *I had come too far before I realized it.*

<sup>(The tense in the translation above is somewhat confusing. I know... I guess that's what the line actually means.)</sup>